# How do I use interfaces with "fallback" parameters in the methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, interface, api-design

I am writing some code in java, and am struggling with deciding if this is Ok code since I've never had any real education. I want to force use save(ConfigurationSection) in my classes, but if not available allow for using save(String). I realize I could just do this conversion before I'd call this method. Is that what I am supposed to be doing?

```java
public interface Serializable {

    default void save(String path){
        save(Claims.getDataManager().getData().createSection(path));
    }
    void save(ConfigurationSection section);

}
```

I'd like to know if I am allowed to do this. Also any good resources that are relatively comprehendable for someone without any real knowledge of jargon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to force use `save(ConfigurationSection)` in my classes

It's difficult to force the user to use one overloaded method over another. If I have two options, I choose the simplest one and let the API do all the dirty work for me. I will not be constructing a `ConfigurationSection` on my own if there is an enticing `String` option unless the former offers me a more flexible/fine-grained/performant way.

You may document these methods well, though. Stating clearly which method is preferable, and why.

> if not available allow for using `save(String)`

I didn't get it. There is either one method or two methods. If the user can't build a `ConfigurationSection`, it doesn't mean `save(ConfigurationSection)` magically disappears, and `save(String)` appears. Your interface is still these two methods.

> I'd like to know if I am allowed to do this.

Yes, you are. Your code looks absolutely fine to me.

```
Claims.getDataManager().getData().createSection(path)
```

is OK as a default way to turn a `String` into a `ConfigurationSection` as long as it doesn't bring any side-effects, and is transparent to the caller. It's like a shortcut that the user is (or can get) familiar with.

*I like your question, by the way. It looks simple and humble.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing such `default` method it seems to be better to create a `fromString` adapter method inside your `ConfigurationSection` class

```
public static ConfigurationSection fromString(String s) {
    // ...
}
```

or event better, in case you have some additional logic to be applied to create builder class

```
public class ConfigurationSectionBuilder {
    // dependencies and constructors
    private DataManagerData dataManagerData;

    public ConfigurationSection fromString(String s) {
        return dataManagerData.createSection(s);
    }
}
```

Interface should be as simple as that. What od you want to add new way of creating `ConfigurationSection` (let say from `Long`), and you will need some additional service dependency for this? It's obvious violetion of *SRP*

---

Also don't create 'chains' like this

```
Claims.getDataManager().getData().createSection(path)
```

It's violetion of *Law of Demeter*